# Why won't my calculations for this code work?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double pay;
        pay = 0.00;

        double add;
        add = 0.00;


        int age;
        age = int.Parse(txtAge.Text);

        string month;
        month = txtMonth.Text;


           if (age >= 18 && age <= 55)
           {
               pay = 350;
           }

           else if (age <= 18)
           {
               pay = 150;                   //if-else-if statements depending on age
           }

           else if (age > 55)
           {
               pay = 35;
           }

        switch (month)
        {
            case "January":
            case "january":
            case "July":
            case "july":          //switch statement, how much you pay depending on month
                add = 100;
                break;


            case "February":
            case "february":
            case "August":
            case "august":
                add = 120;
                break;

            case "March":
            case "march":
            case "September":
            case "september":
                add = 140;
                break;

            case "April":
            case "april":
            case "October":
            case "october":
                add = 160;
                break;

            case "May":
            case "may":
            case "November":
            case "november":
                add = 180;
                break;

            case "June":
            case "june":
            case "December":
            case "december":
                add = 120;
                break;
        }

           lblTotal.Content = (pay + add) * 1.13; //calculation that prints to the label

    }
```

So when I run the code it just outputs 0 in the label
If I put the Calculation at the bottom (seen here) it will say something about the label not being reachable. Any help would be great. Code has been solved

Comment: You have to put the `lblTotal.Content = (pay + add) * 1.13;` outside the switch statement.

Comment: Also, there is a bug: the first and second if statements will execute for if age = 18.

Comment: Not realy, Joel. Only the first one. As the second is an else-if statement, it will be discarded by the first.

Comment: @vicmota, that's correct. Disregard my previous comment. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested your label assignment was inside the `switch` statement causing it not to execute unless the month was June or December.

In any case, I'd suggest though that you simplify.

Try this:

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int age = int.Parse(txtAge.Text);
    double pay = age <= 18 ? 150.0 : (age > 55 ? 35.0 : 350.0);

    int index = (DateTime.Parse("1 " + txtMonth.Text).Month - 1) % 6;
    double[] choices = new [] { 100.0, 120.0, 140.0, 160.0, 180.0, 120.0 };
    double add = choices[index];

    lblTotal.Content = (pay + add) * 1.13;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You can directly assign variables. Declaration and assignment need not be different statements.
2. 18 has two different checks: >= 18 in the if, and <= 18 in the first else if. Not a code error but a semantics error.
3. The final assignment is inside the switch block and unreachable. Put it outside the switch.

It looks like you're using WPF? If so, you should have a look at the MVVM pattern, as well as data binding. It's a good bit to learn and not easy but very important in WPF. It will eliminate the need for querying and writing properties of elements in most cases, though – because that will be handled by the runtime.

Also consider using a ComboBox for the month. Way easier to validate the data.

Answer (score 0):

The label assignment was inside the switch statement. There's a lot of other improvements you can make to code as well.

For starters, you can also join assignment and declaration of variables and use .ToLower() in switch to save yourself the extra cases:

```
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var pay = 0.00;
        var add = 0.00;
        var age = int.Parse(txtAge.Text);
        var month = txtMonth.Text;

        if (age >= 18 && age <= 55)
        {
            pay = 350;
        }
        else if (age <= 18)
        {
            pay = 150;
        }
        else if (age > 55)
        {
            pay = 35;
        }

        switch (month.ToLower())
        {
            case "january":
            case "july":
                add = 100;
                break;

            case "february":
            case "august":
            case "june":
            case "december":
                add = 120;
                break;

            case "march":
            case "september":
                add = 140;
                break;

            case "april":
            case "october":
                add = 160;
                break;

            case "may":
            case "november":
                add = 180;
                break;
        }

        lblTotal.Text = Convert.ToString((pay + add) * 1.13); //calculation that prints to the label
    }
```